# An IQ test for the brave

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, letters

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Monthly Topic Challenge #2: IQ Puzzle Parody](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7376/)</sub>

---

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\text{Cr} & \text{Br} & \text{Rl} \\
\hline
\text{Je} & \text{Ud} & \text{Ft}  \\  
\hline
\text{Dr} & \text{Mr} & \text{?} \\  
\hline
\end{array} \\  
  \\  
\\\text{A. Lr } \\ \text{B. Ml} \\ \text{C. Dr}
$$

What does this IQ test represent, and what's the correct answer?

Hints:

> The brave and lucky, this is as simple as it may seem

> The letters correspond to head and tail

> The words hidden are for characters, where would one see a 3x3 grid related to fighters?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately, it took me until the third hint to get somewhere but this IQ test represents:

> The [*Alignment Chart*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alignment_(Dungeons_%26_Dragons)) from Dungeons & Dragons!
>
>  [image: D&D Alignment Chart]

Using this we can find

> The named *archetypes* associated with the alignments in the table line up with the head and tail letters from the question.
>
>  - [Lawful Good](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alignment_(Dungeons_%26_Dragons)#Lawful_good), **C**rusade**r**
>  - [Neutral Good](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alignment_(Dungeons_%26_Dragons)#Neutral_good), **B**enefacto**r**
>  - [Chaotic Good](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alignment_(Dungeons_%26_Dragons)#Chaotic_good), **R**ebe**l**
>  - [Lawful Neutral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alignment_(Dungeons_%26_Dragons)#Lawful_neutral), **J**udg**e**
>  - [True Neutral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alignment_(Dungeons_%26_Dragons)#True_neutral), **U**ndecide**d**
>  - [Chaotic Neutral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alignment_(Dungeons_%26_Dragons)#Chaotic_neutral), **F**ree Spiri**t**
>  - [Lawful Evil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alignment_(Dungeons_%26_Dragons)#Lawful_evil), **D**ominato**r**
>  - [Neutral Evil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alignment_(Dungeons_%26_Dragons)#Neutral_evil), **M**alefacto**r**

and finally,

> - [Chaotic Evil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alignment_(Dungeons_%26_Dragons)#Chaotic_evil), **D**estroye**r** => Dr => ***Answer C!***.

Comment: Who else has never played d&d?

Comment: Good job! Although simple, I'm surprised it took so long to solve

Comment: @Auribouros -- I was actually really close at one point but rot13(V unq arire urneq bs gur nepurglcrf) and instead I was trying to use things like rot13(svtugre, jvmneq, ebthr, be oneq). This fits very nicely into the IQ quiz format. Good puzzle! :D